# Set property of qml object using c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have tried with

```
 widget->setProperty("text1Text", QVariant("After..."));
```

in my C++,
and

```
 Button
 {
    property alias text1Text: text1.text
    Text
    {
        id: text1
        text: "Initial"
    }   
 }
```

in qml. 
widget is a QQuickWidget object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

See [Interacting with QML Objects from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html).

If you are using `QQmlEngine`:

```
// Using QQmlComponent
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
...
QObject * root = engine.rootObjects().first();
```

If you are using `QQuickView`:

```
QQuickView view;
...
QObject * root = view.rootObject();
```

Getting `text1`:

```
// Update Qml file
Text
{
    id: text1
    text: "Initial"
    objectName: id
} 

// Find text1 in c++
QObject * o1 = root->findChild<QObject *>(QStringLiteral("text1"));
QQuickItem *text1 = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(o1);

// Set property
text1->setProperty("text", QVariant());
```

Comment: It looks like engine does not have a rootObjects() member, only rootContext()

Comment: Yes, `rootObjects()` appeared in [QQmlAllicationEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html). I fixed samples.